# Obtaining same Base64 encoded output of encrypted string in Java and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, base64, urlencode

After getting byte array `encryptedMessageInBytes` from AES encryption function call `cipher.doFinal` in Java, I convert the byte array to base64 like this:

```
String encryptedMessageInBase64 = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(encryptedMessageInBytes));
```

In JavaScript, I simply do `.toString()` to the output I get from `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` method and I get exact same base64 string. i.e.

```
var encryptedMessageInBase64 = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase").toString();
```

It gives same base64 string as in Java code.

However, in one of the Java source code, they have done like this:

```
String encryptedMessageInBase64 = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedMessageInBytes);
```

What shall I do in JavaScript to obtain same base64 string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is answer:

> However, in one of the Java source code, they have done like this:
>
> String encryptedMessageInBase64 = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedMessageInBytes);*

Here, basically they have done `UrlEncoding` instead of Base64 encoding. It is nothing but replacing `+` and `/` characters with `-` and `_` characters. Url encoding is when we want to send encoded string over HTTP where it treats these two as special characters this is why we need to replace them with some other characters which are HTTP friendly.